# Where should trigger for nextval on insert reside: in schema or in form?

Tags: triggers, insert, oracle11g, oracleforms

I want to insert a record into a table (inkpen) via an Oracle Form and I want to use this trigger to create the next inkpen_id.

```
create trigger inkpen_trigger_1
       before insert on inkpen
  for each row
      begin 
      select inpken_id.nextval into :new.pen_id from dual;
  end;
```

**Questions:**

Where should this trigger reside: in the schema or in the form?

If it is part of the schema can my form call it?

I'm thinking it should be part of the schema because it may be necessary to insert a record outside the form and the nextval logic will already be in place.

My DBA says I need to imbed this trigger logic into the form.

I'm asking this because I don't have rights to create the trigger so I can test and
the DBA is hesitant to create it for me.

For what it's worth, here's my [fiddle for the trigger logic](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd6ae)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it in the `pre-insert` trigger of your block for the table inkpen in your form.

Comment: Is that where I should put it? Suppose I want to insert a record without using the form and I want keep the integrity of the nextval. In such an instance, do I need to create another trigger, outside the form,  using the same logic of the form?

Comment: If it should always be applicable it should be with a database trigger. And then the solution you proposed is correct. But you did say the DBA didn't like it and that you should do it on the form. With my solution you do it on the form and ONLY on the form.